# Работа с CSV форматом в Python

Tags: python, csv

Впервые сталкиваюсь с CSV форматом. Для экспериментов создал файл `example.csv` с таким вот содержимым:

```
first name, last name, module1, module2, module3, description
student, best, 100, 100, 100, Excellent score
student, good, 90, "90,2", 100, "Good score
but could do better"
```

Проблема в том, что, на сколько я понимаю, значения отделенные кавычками должны идти слитно как одно значение. Но когда я выполняю следующий скрипт:

```
import csv

with open("D:\\pytest\example.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Я наблюдаю такой вот результат:

```
['first name', ' last name', ' module1', ' module2', ' module3', ' description']
['student', ' best', ' 100', ' 100', ' 100', ' Excellent score']
['student', ' good', ' 90', ' "90', '2"', ' 100', ' "Good score']
['but could do better"']
```

Почему 90 и 2 в третьей строке идут отдельно и в конце строке пишется не слитно ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется ваш csv файл не совсем csv файл, потому что после запятых не должно быть пробелов

```
>>> csv_text = """first name,last name,module1,module2,module3,description
... student,best,100,100,100,Excellent score
... student,good,90,"90,2",100,"Good score
... but could do better"
... """
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(csv_text)
>>> list(csv.reader(f))
[['first name', 'last name', 'module1', 'module2', 'module3', 'description'], ['student', 'best', '100', '100', '100', 'Excellent score'], ['student', 'good', '90', '90,2', '100', 'Good score\nbut could do better']]
```

Однако и эту проблему можно решить при помощи аргумента [skipinitialspace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace):

```
>>> csv_text2 = """first name, last name, module1, module2, module3, description
... student, best, 100, 100, 100, Excellent score
... student, good, 90, "90,2", 100, "Good score
... but could do better" """
>>> 
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(csv_text2)
>>> list(csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True))
[['first name', 'last name', 'module1', 'module2', 'module3', 'description'], ['student', 'best', '100', '100', '100', 'Excellent score'], ['student', 'good', '90', '90,2', '100', 'Good score\nbut could do better ']]
```